# Unable to start the Kafka instance using docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I am trying to run the multibroker kafka setup and Below is my docker-compose.yml file

```
 version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zoom
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka1:
      image: wurstmeister/kafka
      container_name: kafkacont1
      ports:
        - "9092:9092"
      environment:
          KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
          KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
          KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
          KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
          KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
          KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

  kafka2:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafkacont2
    ports:
      - "9093:9093"
    environment:
          KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
          KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
          KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka2:9093,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:39092
          KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
          KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
          KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

when I run `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d`

the terminal says the containers are created , but when I do `docker ps` I don't see those containers

Comment: Just try `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up` and check what errors/warnings printed on screen

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram yes I ran without -d flag and I got a error saying I have to add KAFKA_LISTENERS variable if I have to use KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS and I added  KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092 for kafka1 and it worked

Comment: Keep in mind that both brokers are competing for resources of the same machine, therefore won't be as fast as just one broker and isn't truly fault tolerant

Comment: @Thejas So your issue is fixed? if so please post it as an answer

Comment: @OneCricketeer fault tolerant means?

Comment: @Thejas One of the main benefits of Kafka is that data can be replicated. If one broker fails, then others can still serve the same data... Obviously, if your one machine fails (your Docker host), then all brokers (and zookeepers) are dead. Therefore, there is no real benefit to exposing those services outside of the Docker network

Answer (score 1):

My updated docker-compose.yml file, to use **KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS** we need to provide **KAFKA_LISTENERS**

```
 version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    container_name: zoom
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka1:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafkacont1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

  kafka2:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafkacont2
    ports:
      - "9093:9093"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka2:9093,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:39092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka2:9093,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:39092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
```

I have added  **KAFKA_LISTENERS** variable to both the kafka services